# Integrate IPhone Safari like view in Android?

Tags: iphone, android, safari, view, gallery

The main concept goes like this. I have four listviews with its own
data loaded at the same time. Only one listview will be visible to the
user. Now, when the user presses a button, not only the current
listview but also other three listviews should be minimized and then
user can just scroll just as in Gallery and select the listview that
one wants to open.

I hope you all have understood what I want.

Let me know if someone have some idea of implementing such a User
Interface in Android.

Comment: You want a UINavigationController type interface?

Comment: I want to replicate IPhone Safari like animation in Android Application. The way Iphone Safari minimizes the tab and then we can select any of the tab and open that Window. 

This kind of View has been implemented in TweetDeck for Iphone. 

I want the similar interface in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either [View.draw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)) or [View.getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()) depending on what suits you best. Then just display them using `Gallery` or something similar.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to use View.draw and View.getDrawingCache for this purpose? It will be great if you can help me out in this regard

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally, I was able to do it.